How to associate in WhatsApp Business Platform a phone number certificate with a phone number?
My app sends booking reminders using the WhatsApp Cloud API. Everything works as expected with the test number. I added the company number and verified it with the SMS code. In the WhatsApp Manager, the status of the number is "waiting," and it says that I need to associate the certificate with the number. I have the certificate and tried to follow the documentation linked near the certificate. However, it leads me to the on-premises documentation, which is not relevant for the Cloud API. Can you please help me figure out what I am missing?
The Cloud API has nothing on certificate association.

Eventually, I realized where the problem was, it seems that Meta doesn't update its documentation quickly enough. The On-Premises API is sunsetting, so we can't use the documentation from the certificate.
We only need to register the number using the endpoint "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/[phone-number-id]/register" without associating any certificate.
Here is the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/registration
